# Difference between "meeting" and "have a meeting with"

Tags: meaning, phrases, meaning-in-context

Is there a set in stone distinction between the meaning of the phrases "meeting someone" and "have a meeting with someone"? It is clear to me that the first implies a first meeting and the second does not.

But would that make "it was nice meeting you" incorrect, if you have met the person before?

Answer (score 9):

One phrase uses *meeting* as a verb and the other as a noun. The verb emphasises the interaction while the noun emphasises the formality. So if you were getting together informally, you'd probably say that you were *meeting someone*, whereas if you had a set agenda and purpose for the gathering, you might prefer to say that you attended *a meeting* with them.

> **meet** *verb*
> 1 Arrange or happen to come into the presence or company of (someone)
> [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/meet)
>
> **meet with** *verb*
> 1.3 Have a meeting with (someone)
> [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/meet)
>
> **meeting** *noun*
> 1 An assembly of people for a particular purpose, especially for formal discussion.
> [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/meeting)

There is considerable semantic overlap between the phrases; definition 1.3 of *meet* as a verb even references the noun definition: "have a meeting with (someone)".

If you start with the noun form "has a meeting with", you can replace it with the verb form "is meeting *with*". Note that dropping *with* in the verb form tends to refer to an informal 'gathering', so going from the plain "*is meeting*" to "*has a meeting with*" tends to produce something significantly less idiomatic.

Comment: "[I]f you must draw a difference" -- I must! To have a meeting is much more specific than just to meet. Suppose you're arranging a night out with friends. You would _never_ say "Let's have a meeting at the pub and then go for dinner" because that would always be interpreted as a bizarre invitation to something like a business meeting. You'd say "Let's meet at the pub and then go for dinner" and it would be interpreted as meaning that the pub is the place where you'll find each other.

Comment: @DavidRicherby The existence of the portion of semantic difference doesn't detract from the existence of the considerable portion of semantic overlap.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I see your point, though, and have edited my answer to identify the semantic overlap and difference more clearly.

Comment: @DavidRicherby David this one I agree with much more than the other example you posted below my answer. See the comments below under my answer. I think Lawrence has probably given the most eloquent answer but I just think there was a little confusion on this one. Take a look at my comments below and let me know what you think if you wish. Thanks!

Comment: I still think this talk of "semantic overlap" is glossing over a very significant difference between "meeting somebody" and "have a meeting with somebody". The answer still suggests that they're basically the same thing, but with some nuanced differences. They're not: they're completely different.

Answer (score 7):

I don't think the phrase *meeting someone* necessarily implies having a first meeting. In fact I am much more likely to assume that it's *not* a first meeting. If Mark said:

> I am meeting Dave for lunch at Hesburger

I would assume that Mark already knows Dave.

Only if Mark said:

> I am meeting Dave for the first time

would I think that it was a first meeting.

The phrase *meeting someone* is such that the sentence it is in usually doesn't end there. It's not very common to hear someone say something like:

> I am meeting Dave.

It's more commonly used in the form:

> I am meeting Dave *somewhere* or *to do something*.

and in that sort of situation, it implies that you are at least aware that Dave exists and it may/may not the first time you two are meeting face to face.

The main difference between the two phrases is that, *having a meeting with someone* refers to a more formal and set sort of meeting; the kind of meeting you would have at work or with a client. You wouldn't *have a meeting with someone* if you were just meeting for lunch or to go to the movies. The difference is in the formality of the meeting you are having.

And yes, *it was nice meeting you* or *it was nice to meet you* (which I hear more) are used when you have just met someone. You could use *it was nice meeting **with** you* or *thanks for meeting with me* at the end of a meeting if it's not the first time you have met that person but it sounds rather formal.

Answer (score 3):

"I'm meeting someone" and "I have a meeting with someone" are very similar and basically mean the same thing. The first doesn't necessarily imply a first meeting. I think what you mean is a little different. And actually you have it backward. "I'm meeting someone" is more casual (I think that's what you meant) and could mean that you are meeting a friend after work. 'I have a meeting with someone" is a little more formal. But it can also be used to mean the same exact thing.

*Examples:*

1. P1: "Do you want to get drinks after work?"
   P2: "Sorry, I cant, I'm meeting someone."
2. P1: "Do you want to get drinks after work?"
   P2: "Sorry, I can't, I have a meeting with someone."

These examples mean the same thing but the second is more formal and would typically mean you are not just going to meet a friend or have a casual meeting or date. It would usually mean that you have something much more formal and important, possibly even a first meeting with a business partner or job recruiter.

"It was nice meeting you" is used typically only after you meet someone the first time, after the meeting, or at some point in the future when you see them again. Also, you would not keep saying it after having said it once or twice unless some significant time had gone by.

*Examples:*

1. A meeting is ending. You shake hands and you say, "It was nice meeting you. I hope we can do it again soon.".
2. You had a first meeting with someone last week, now you see them at the grocery store today, you might say, "Hi, there, John, it's good to see you. It was nice meeting with you last week. Maybe we can do it again soon?"

Comment: I disagree. To meet somebody merely means to be with them at some place and time: "Let's meet at the railway station at 7pm" just means that we'll both find each other there at that time. In contrast, a meeting is a business (or similar) event where a group of people get together to discuss some specific topic. If you say "Let's have a meeting at the railway station at 7pm", I'll wonder why you've chosen such a strange location and why it's outside normal working hours.

Comment: I think there is some confusion. "Meeting" doesn't always mean a business meeting or similar (like "I'm in a meeting"). As in my example (or Lawrence's who put it a little more eloquently), it depends how its used. "I'm meeting someone" is a casual use, even if you say, "I'm meeting someone at 7". It indicates it's casual (usually - not always). "I have a meeting with someone..." is almost always to refer to something more formal, possibly someone you don't know, business meeting.... In your example it's odd b/c you are using the noun form of "meeting", not the gerund form of "meet".

Comment: @DavidRicherby The sentence needs to change to something like , "I'm meeting someone at the train station at 7". Now it's in gerund form and is much more casual. Most people will think you have a "date" or something like that. The other way, yes, it's a little odd.

Comment: The question is about the difference between "meeting somebody" and "have a meeting with somebody"; the difference between "I meet" and "I am meeting" is just a change of tense, which is irrelevant. You're confusing participles and gerunds. "I'm meeting" is a participle (verb) not a gerund (noun). The gerund is something like "My meeting him at the station was a great surprise"; which is very rare. "Meeting" as a noun is almost always the business-meeting meaning, rather than the gerund of the verb _to meet_; "meeting" as a participle could be either, depending on the rest of the sentence.

Comment: But let's use the wording from the question. "I'm meeting someone at the train station" means that we're going to find each other there; "I'm having a meeting with someone at the train station" means we're having something like a business meeting. Nothing has changed.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I have to get to bed so I'll add more later but yes I meant to say present participle as opposed to gerund. That was my bad. I don't have them confused I just transposed them on accident. Sorry. This is how we speak in the US though. As in, "Sorry, I can't, I'm meeting someone tonight.". It's almost always casual and means a date or informal gathering. Anyway, maybe we are mixing things up? All the answers here basically indicate the same thing. We can discuss more tomorrow, if you like. It's super late here, 5:30am (yikes!) and I'm doing off as I write...heh. Ttyl!

Comment: We seem to be agreed on the meaning of "I'm meeting someone". But you claim that "I'm having a meeting with someone" means the same thing and _that's_ what I disagree with.

Comment: I would refer to Lawrence's post. I think his is more eloquent. I see what you are saying now. I may edit my answer to be more clear. FYI I don't mean those 2 are always the same. They can be. But you are correct the 2nd is much more formal and usually would mean the noun "a meeting". I agree. What people mean about semantic overlap is it's not always clear if the verb participle form is being used or the verb gerund noun form or the actual noun of "a meeting" outside the colloquial context of a native speaker. No one disagrees that "a meeting" is a gathering of people.

Answer (score 2):

"[To have a meeting with](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/meeting)" must have some duration - it's not a point event.

"[To meet with](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/meet)" *may* be a synonym of the above, but it can also be used for an instance.

For example, if I say "*I'll be meeting Jim at the airport*", it probably means that I'm picking him up, and we're not *having a meeting* with a set of things to discuss.  In no way does it imply a **first meeting** - I already know Jim, but we're not currently in the same place; when we are in the same place and see each other, then we have met again.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a set in stone distinction between the meaning of the phrases "meeting someone" and "have a meeting with someone"?

Yes. In the phrase "have a meeting", a meeting is an arranged event at which a group of people come together to discuss a particular topic. The phrase is most commonly used to refer to business meetings, at which a group of employees discuss, for example, the work they intend to do on a particular project.  At a political meeting, members of a political organization would get together to discuss the party's policies and so on.

"To meet somebody" just means to come into their presence, either accidentally or deliberately.  "Let's meet at the railway station at 7pm" means "Let's both go to the railway station at 7pm and find each other." Presumably, we'd then catch a train together to go somewhere, or maybe it's just that the station is a convenient location to find each other and then we'll go do something else.  In contrast, "Let's have a meeting at the railway station at 7pm" would be rather strange – it would be an invitation to something like a business meeting but in a very unusual location for that.

"Meet" can also be unplanned.  "I met John in the park" could just mean that I'd gone to the park and I happened to find John there.  Or it could mean that the first time I ever spoke to John was in the park.  If you wanted to emphasize that, you could say "I first met John in the park."

> It is clear to me that the first implies a first meeting and the second does not.

"Meet" doesn't have to be for the first time, as the "Let's meet at the railway station" example shows.  And one could meet somebody for the first time in a meeting: for example, it would be very common for employees of a company and customers to meet each other for the first time at business meetings.

Answer (score 0):

'Meeting someone' implies that one is meeting with a friend, acquaintance or anyone in general for business or any other reason.
e.g.1) I'm meeting Meera for lunch.
2) I met him at the mall yesterday.

However, 'Having a meeting with someone' usually means that the meeting was arranged or scheduled earlier.

Comment: But even if you and I pre-arrange to go for a social lunch together, we'd never say "We've arranged a meeting at the cafe" because, then, people would assume we were having something like a business meeting.  We'd say "We're meeting at the cafe."